# Responding to AJAX GET and POST requests with Google App Engine (Python)

Tags: python, ajax, google-app-engine, http, webapp2

I have confusion on how the servers(here app engine) respond to AJAX GET and POST requests. I want send a GET request to my server and get some JSON data back.

Here is the AJAX GET request

```
function syncRestoreLinks(e) {

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "/sync"

    request.open("GET", url);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState === 4) {
        console.log(request.responseText);
        }
    }
    request.send(null);
    console.log("Getting links from db");
}
```

Handler on the server side

```
class SyncHandler(Handler):
    def get(self):
        response_data = {"loggedIn":False, "linkData":None, "success":False}
        json_txt = json.dumps(response_data)
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
        self.response.out.write(json_txt)

    def post(self):
        response_data = {"loggedIn":False, "linkData":None, "success":False}
        json_txt = json.dumps(response_data)
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
        self.response.out.write(json_txt)
```

This handler writes my response data out to the screen where as I want it to send it back and let JS handle it. (I am able to use server redirects here.)

If I make a POST request instead, the code works the way I intend it to. But here, I cannot make server redirects or render pages and only the script making request has that control.

Is this how GET/POST responses work or I am doing something stupid in my code?

Is there any way for GET response not to be written on the page and be sent to JS? In the code above the responseText is an empty string but, the json is printed on screen.

Comment: Are you using webapp2 to link the url `/sync` to `SyncHandler`?

Comment: yes, webapp2 and python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing AJAX Get requests successfully with app engine right now.

Your sync handler looks correct.  Are you sure it is being called?  Add a `logging.info()` statement there to make sure.  If it is being called, then I suspect the error is on the front end.  I use jQuery and not `XMLHttpRequest` so I can't you help you with that.  My jQuery call looks like this:

```
    $.get(url, callback_function, 'json');
```

Comment: does your response.out.write call sends json data back to JS function or prints it to the screen?

Comment: It sends JSON data back.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a POST handler to your `SyncHandler` like this:

```
def post(self):
    ...
    self.response.out.write(json_txt)
```

The strange part is that your POST request should not be working without this code to handle the request.  You only show a `get()` method in your code.

Comment: I think my I didn't phrase my question accurately. I didn't show the post method in my code, but as you say it's same as get. What I wanted to know was why these requests work in that way. A more general question about AJAX requests.

Comment: Oh, now I understand your question.  It's possible to specify a redirect on a POST request if you send a 307 status code as mentioned here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/99894/144312

Comment: An AJAX response should be a JSON object, not a rendered page.

Comment: I can understand how POST seems to work. Is there any way for GET response not to be written on the page and be sent to JS. In the code above the responseText is an empty string but, the json is printed on screen.

Comment: This is a different question.  The original question is "Responding to AJAX GET and POST requests with Google App Engine (Python)", not about handling AJAX responses.  Please ask a new question (or search for it first).